# Trouble reading JSON output in SAS

Tags: json, sas

I am trying to parse out data from a JSON file in SAS but am getting stuck in my code.  I can't post all of the JSON content because it's too long, but I can post part of it that's relevant.  Here is my SAS code below; when I run it, I get something in the log that says "LOST CARD" and I'm not sure what that means.

Part of the code is commented out because the code actually works until I get further down on my variable list...I wonder...does this error ("LOST CARD") have something to do with the "lrecl" line and the length of certain variables?

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to provide!

SAS Code:

```
filename otp1 '...\output\otp1.json';

data work.otp1sas;
infile otp1 lrecl = 32000 /*truncover*/ scanover;
input 

@'"startTime":' startTime $20. 
@'"endTime":' endTime $20.
@'"walkTime":' walkTime $20. 
@'"transitTime":' transitTime $20. 
/*@'"waitingTime":' waitingTime $20. 
@'"walkDistance":' walkDistance $20. 
@'"walkLimitExceeded":' walkLimitExceeded $20. 
@'"transfers":' transfers $20.*/;

startTime = scan(startTime,1,',"');
endTime = scan(endTime,1,',"');
walkTime = scan(walkTime,1,',"');
transitTime = scan(transitTime,1,',"');
/*waitingTime = scan(waitingTime,1,',"');
walkDistance = scan(walkDistance,1,',"');
walkLimitExceeded = scan(walkLimitExceeded,1,',"');
transfers = scan(transfers,1,',"');*/

run;
```

JSON Content (that's relevant for the code above):

```
{"requestParameters":{"date":"03-14-2014","mode":"TRANSIT,WALK","arriveBy":"false","showIntermediateStops":"false","fromPlace":"33.8134605,-84.34973148","itinIndex":"0","toPlace":"33.80882004,-84.39769799","time":"10:00am","maxWalkDistance":"3218.688"},"plan":{"date":1394805600000,"from":{"name":"Arlington Avenue Northeast","stopId":null,"stopCode":null,"platformCode":null,"lon":-84.34880165944314,"lat":33.81255118156955,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"orig":null,"zoneId":null,"stopIndex":null},"to":{"name":"Collier Road Northwest","stopId":null,"stopCode":null,"platformCode":null,"lon":-84.39787235641106,"lat":33.808417712941896,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"orig":null,"zoneId":null,"stopIndex":null},"itineraries":[{"duration":2630.0,"startTime":1394806613000,"endTime":1394809243000,"walkTime":994,"transitTime":1273,"waitingTime":363,"walkDistance":1280.0733818655874,"walkLimitExceeded":false,"elevationLost":0.0,"elevationGained":0.0,"transfers":2,"
```

Comment: SAS expects more data on current line, but the line ended. Why you're not using TRUNCOVER? Maybe this will help http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/058-30.pdf

Comment: What version of SAS are you on? If you're on 9.3+ you can use Proc Groovy to help parse JSON files.

Comment: Reese, thank you.  For someone who's not familiar with converting JSON file content into something usable in SAS, is proc groovy relatively easy to use?  I may consider that option...

Comment: @vasja You shouldn't use TRUNCOVER with `@" "` input, as it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: @emorystudent GROOVY is pretty easy to use, but even better there are nice tutorials, even using SAS.  See [How to import Twitter tweets in SAS Data Step](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sascom/2013/12/12/how-to-import-twitter-tweets-in-sas-data-step-using-oauth-2-authentication-style/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not luccy enough to have SAS 9.3+, you might use the following

```
filename otp1 '...\output\otp1.json';

data work.otp1sas;
    format
        equation $60.
        variable $32.
        value    $32.

        startTime $20. 
        endTime $20.
        walkTime $20. 
        transitTime $20. 
        waitingTime $20. 
        walkDistance $20. 
        walkLimitExceeded $20. 
        transfers $20.;

    ** read the JSON and isolate the relevant object **;
    infile otp1 lrecl = 32000 truncover ;
    input @'"itineraries":[' jsonArray $32000.;
    jsonArray  = scan(jsonArray, 1, ']');

    ** separate the objects **;
    do objNr = 1 to countw(jsonArray, '}{');
        jsonObject = strip(scan(jsonArray, objNr, '}{'));

        ** separate the equations **;
        do varNr = 1 to countw(jsonObject, ',');
            equation = strip(scan(jsonObject, varNr, ','));
            variable = scan(equation, 1, '"');
            value    = substr(equation, index(equation, ':') + 1);

            ** handle cases where a string value contains a comma **;
            do while (varNr LT countw(jsonObject,',')
            and substr(value, 1, 1) EQ '"' 
            and substr(value, length(value), 1) NE '"' );
                varNr = varNr + 1;
                value = trim(value) ||','|| strip(scan(jsonObject, varNr, ','));
            end;

            select (variable);
                when ('startTime')         startTime         = dequote(value);
                when ('endTime')           endTime           = dequote(value);
                when ('walkTime')          walkTime          = dequote(value);
                when ('transitTime')       transitTime       = dequote(value);
                when ('waitingTime')       waitingTime       = dequote(value);
                when ('walkDistance')      walkDistance      = dequote(value);
                when ('walkLimitExceeded') walkLimitExceeded = dequote(value);
                when ('transfer')          transfer          = dequote(value);
                otherwise put varNr= variable= value=;
            end;
        end;
        if countw(jsonObject, ',') GT 1 then output;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS 9.4 has a Proc DS2 solution for processing Json

Comment: Please be more specific and explain if possible.